# Send traffic over specified connections by port

Tags: windows, networking, port

I am currently at a college with an extremely restrictive network. No outbound ports are open except 53, 80, and 443. I can't do any of the things I'd like to do like FTP, SSH, etc., which is obviously extremely annoying. To remedy this, I got a FreedomPop stick which has no such limits, except when it comes to bandwidth, the free plan only having 500MB BW. What I'd like to do, then, is to have port 80 and 443 traffic go over my school's network (wired or wireless, can do either way), and everything else go over the FreedomPop connection (which appears to Windows as a wired connection). How can I force specific ports to go out over specific connections? I'm using Windows 8.1. I have a variety of other networking hardware around, including several different wireless cards and two wireless routers, and I can acquire more if needed. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: you could set up a `socks proxy` to use the alternative route and then   make apps like ssh client use that

Comment: How would this be done?